# Does sort -u convert case?

Tags: files, sort, string, case-sensitivity

If I have a file with some words starting with Capital letters and some starts with Small letters and some start with numbers or special characters. Does using `sort -u input > output` convert the letter in the input file to lower case in the output file?

For some reason this seems what happened with me. However, if not, I need a method to first convert the capital letters initials if found to small.

Comment: You can easily test your assumption by running `printf "World\nhello\nworld\nHello" | sort -u` in `bash` or similar.

Comment: Having said that, it's a bit unclear what your question actually is. Do you want to know about `sort` behaviour, about a way to convert upper to lower case for sorting, or about something else?

Comment: Do you have sample data that behaved in an unexpected way? If so, please [edit it into your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/511531/edit). Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sort` does not alter case, nor does `sort` change the data other than ordering, notwithstanding `sort -u` which removes duplicates.

```
$ for demochar in a b c A B C Ɓ ƀ À à; do printf "%s\n%s\n" "$demochar" "$demochar"; done ) | shuf > input1
$ sort -u input1  > input2
$ sort -uf input1 > input3
$ paste input1 input2 input3
B   A   a
ƀ   B   B
C   C   C
C   a   à
B   b   ƀ
b   c   Ɓ
à   À
a   à
à   ƀ
c   Ɓ
c
A
ƀ
Ɓ
a
b
Ɓ
A
À
À
```

`sort -f` will *for the purposes of the comparison*, force everything to upper case that it can, but it does not change the actual data being output.  From the manual:

> `-f`, `--ignore-case`
>
> Convert all lowercase characters to their uppercase equivalent before comparison, that is, perform case-independent sorting.